# Documentation based on JSON Schema

Tags: json, documentation, jsonschema

I'd like to use my JSON schemas to generate the documentation.

In the example below, I want to list all combinations ErrorNumber/ErrorMessage available in my output messages in JSON.

But I can't find a way on the object level, my attempts with "examples" or "enum" failed.

Does anyone have a solution?

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "ErrorNumber",
        "ErrorMessage"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "ErrorNumber": {
            "$id": "#root/ErrorNumber", 
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "ErrorMessage": {
            "$id": "#root/ErrorMessage", 
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you mean to write `"$ref"` where you use `"$id"` in the example?
2. Where exactly did you have problems with `enum`? The following works fine for me with a draft-2020-12 Validator (and after removing your "$id"!):

```
{
  // ... your JSON here ...
  "enum": [
    {"ErrorNumber": 200, "ErrorMessage": "OK"},
    {"ErrorNumber": 404, "ErrorMessage": "Not found."}
    // ...
  ]
}
```

3. Different approaches, in case you still can change that:

If your error numbers start at 0 and are contiguous, then an Array of messages might serve your purpose.

Alternatively an object with numerical keys might:

```
{
  "200": "OK",
  "404": "Not found."
}
```